# How to set consumer to start from a specific offset in Golang Kafka 10

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

My need is to make the producer to start from the last message it processed before it crashed. Fortunately I am in the case of having only one topic, with one partition and one consumer.

To do so I tried https://github.com/Shopify/sarama but it doesn't seems to be available yet. 
I am now using https://godoc.org/github.com/bsm/sarama-cluster, which allow me to commit every message offset.

I cannot retrieve the last committed offset
I cannot figure out how to make a sarama [consumer](https://godoc.org/github.com/bsm/sarama-cluster#Consumer) to start from said offset. The only parameter I've found so far is `Config.Producer.Offsets.Initial`.

1. How to retrieve the last committed offset?
2. How to  make the consumer start from the last message whose offset has been committed? `OffsetNewest` will make it start from the last message produced, not the last processed b the consumer.
3. Is it possible to do so using only Shopify/sarama and not bsm/sarama-cluster ?

Thank in advance

P.S. I am using Kafka 10.0, so the offsets are stores in a kafka and not in zookeeper.

**EDIT1:**
Partial solution: fetch all the messages since sarama.OffsetOldest and skip all of them until we found a non processed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If offset was already saved for a partition, sarama-cluster will resume consumption from that offset. The `Config.Producer.Offsets.Initial` option is used only if no saved offset is present (first run for a consumer group).

You can verify this by adding the following line at the beginning of your `main()` function:

```
sarama.Logger = log.New(os.Stdout, "sarama: ", log.LstdFlags)
```

Then you'll see something like the following in the output:

`cluster/consumer CID-17db1be4-a162-411c-a106-4d198191176a consume sample/0 from 12`

The 12 in that is the offset Sarama is going to start from for that partition (sample/0).